# minimizing importing libraries like jquery, loading once into 3 htmls

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 html files, and in each html file I'm importing jQuery, bootstrap or another library, etc.

I feel that there is not a need for loading jQuery 3 separate times and there should be a way I can preload it and pass it to my 3 html files.

Is there a solution to do this?
Im very new to html and javascript

Comment: Well...yes. And you don't have to do anything. Browsers already cache resources so if several pages all reference the same file, the browser will download it once and fetch it from cache for subsequent requests.

Comment: Also, you can run a simple check to see if jquery has been loaded before trying to load it again.

Comment: how do we test for this? if indeed the browser fetches from cache then we can not prove if the test returns scripts from cache/other html or from the  current html because the browser will have to find our import in the 2nd file

Comment: since jquery and bootstrap are common to all the files why not just create a main html file and dynamically inject the 3 different views into it. Jquery and angularjs are awesome for this. Php includes could also be used here.